# Move all open applications to current desktop "space" with applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, desktop, display

I have been searching endlessly with no avail on how to move a window between spaces on macos in applescript. The seemingly basic thing I want to do is move all open application windows from any space to the first space. If anyone out there can help, please reach out. There seems to be no straight forward way in doing this in the latest version of macos (Mojave 10.14.4). I am also open to doing this in any another language that will interact with macos if it is possible/simpler.

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with proc in application processes where background only is false
        tell proc
            log "found app: " & name
            set processName to name
            log count of windows
            repeat with win in windows
              -- move window to first "space"
            end repeat
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is just simulating moving spaces using 
`tell application "System Events" to key code 19 using {control down}`
but then your desktop will bounce for each app like crazy.

Comment: how would that work with each individual window like the above code in the window loop?

Answer (score 0):

There's a window manager for macOS called [Phoenix](https://github.com/kasper/phoenix) that's scriptable using JavaScript.

I wrote a Phoenix script, [phoenix-move-windows](https://github.com/Mooninaut/phoenix-move-windows) that moves windows based on the current monitor and screen layout. It is configurable so that it will move windows to a specified position, and you can have different arrangements based on the current number of screens, and number of spaces on each screen.

It does support moving all windows to a specified screen and space, using the "defaultBinding" in an arrangement.